# JavaScript- How to change "message" div to yellow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to know how to change a "message" div to yellow.  Below are my js, html, and css files.  Also, I'd like to know how to make the data validations work.  The word Male doesn't print out, only the letter M.

```
    Javascript:

// Assignment 7 JavaScript and jQuery
alert ("This is a test.");

//1.)  the DOM is ready

$(document).ready(function()
{

alert("the DOM is ready.");

//2.)  the submitForm function


  var submitForm = function()
  {
  //alert("This is a second test.");
  var first_name = "";
  var last_name = "";
  var gender = "";
  var experience = "";
  var firstName = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
            //from Stack Overflow (Mar '12)
  var Gender = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();          
  /*var M = Male;
  var F = Female;
  var Male;
  var Female;
  var Gender = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();
    if (Gender = M)
      {
      Gender = Male;
      }
    else (Gender = F)
      {
      Gender = Female;
      }
    */
  var Years = document.getElementById("years").value;
  var errorFoundFlag = false;

//3.)  data validation

    if (firstName == "")
    {
    errorFoundFlag = true;
    document.getElementById("first_error").textContent = "You must Enter a First Name.";
    document.getElementById("first_error").style.color = "red";
    }
    else 
    {
    document.getElementById("first_error").textContent = "";
    }
    if (lastName == "")
    {
    errorFoundFlag = true;
    document.getElementById("last_error").textContent = "You must Enter a Last Name.";
    document.getElementById("last_error").style.color = "red";
    }
    else 
    {
    document.getElementById("last_error").textContent = "";
    } 
    if (Gender == "")
    {
    errorFoundFlag = true;
    document.getElementById("gender_error").textContent = "You must Choose a Gender.";
    document.getElementById("gender_error").style.color = "red";
    }
    else 
    {
    document.getElementById("gender_error").textContent = "";
    }
    if (Years == "-")
    {
    errorFoundFlag = true;
    document.getElementById("years_error").text = "You must Select a Number.";
    document.getElementById("years_error").style.color = "red";
    }
    else 
    {
    document.getElementById("years_error").textContent = "";
    }

//4.)  output employment status

    if (errorFoundFlag == false)
    {
    var myMsg = " <h2> Employment Stats for </h2> " + firstName + " " + lastName +
                                        "<br>" +
                                        "You are a: " + Gender +
                                        "<br>" +
                                        "You have:  " + Years + " years experience" ;
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = myMsg;
    //document.
    }

    //make div yellow from book p.281
    $("div").filter("#message").css("backgroundColor", "yellow");

  }    //end submitForm function        

//5.)  onload function

    window.onload = function()
    {
    document.getElementById("mysubmit").onclick = submitForm;

    }

})     //end document ready                                     

    HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Assignment 7</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Asgn7_Pham.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Asgn7_Pham1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="top">
    <h1>Assignment 7</h1>
    <h3>Enter Employment Statistics</h3>
    <form>
        <br>
        <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" required> <span class="error" id="first_error"></span>
        <br>
        <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" required> <span class="error" id="last_error"></span>
        <br>
        Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M">
        Female <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F"> <span class="error" id="gender_error"></span>
        <br>
        Years Experience:
        <select id="years" size="1">
            <option value="-">-</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>

        <span class="error" id="years_error"></span>

        <br><br>
        <input type="button" id="mysubmit" value="Submit Form">
        <br>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div id="message">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

    CSS:

/* type selectors */
article, aside, figure, figcaption, footer, header, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

* {
    margin: 10;
    padding: 10;
}

body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 650px;
    background-color: silver;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 150%;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
    padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px;
}

p {
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.error {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: It only prints out the letter M, because of `value="M"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the message div *is* yellow. Second, you're explicitly getting the value of the checked radio button, which you identify as `value="M"`
See here? : `var Gender = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();` <=== That's where M comes from.

You should just use `value="Male"` if that's your desired result.

Also, on this line: `$("div").filter("#message").css("backgroundColor", "yellow");`.
You don't need to filter the entire DOM when you know the ID of the element.
Just use `$("#message").css("backgroundColor", "yellow");`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I changed the HTML value to "Male".  I hope the professor doesn't get mad at me because I'm  supposed to only code the JS.  Your abbreviated statement for making the message div yellow seems to work better, but it's different from the command the book had.  Very helpful suggestions!

Comment: If he does get mad, I would ask him why are we storing the letter "M" when what are actually interested in is "Male"? "M" is meaningless.

Comment: I put quotation marks around M and Male and the Javascript works.

Comment: @Quang Great! So did anyone's answer help you? If so, please mark it as the answer!

Comment: Mark's and Damiano's answers were the most helpful.  Thank you very much!  I also got the data validation to work properly. //3.)  data validation
 if (lastName == "" && errorFoundFlag == false)
    {
    errorFoundFlag = true;
    $("#last_error").text("You must Enter a Last Name.");
    $("#last_error").css("color", "red");
    }
    else 
    {
     $("#last_error").text("")
    }

Comment: @Quang please mark an answer and the actual answer!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you have asked for, I guess with message div you mean the textarea.

Either way, i revamped your code, you do not need the doc.ready() for submits in general.

The commented out JS of mine is fully functional, will work, the code on line 29-32

```
$("#mysubmit").click(function(){
$(".spanFirst").fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(2300);
});
```

Is just simulating what would happen if first name field was empty, click submit and see:-)

The code following under that is the PHP code, this will work with this Html, JS, just the JS needs bit amendment, if you want, i will do that for you.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/dYKBNL

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and offer.

Comment: No problem:-)
The commented out code is ready to go apart from few details:

Comment: No problem:-)
The commented out code is ready to go apart from few details:
- Take out the lines which are currently not commented out,line 5 and 11 would need slight change.Line 29-32 have to go either way, they're just there as demo, can't run PHP on codepen.
- If the prof wants pure JS, replace lines 5 and 11 with simple alert functions, like the message conditional statement.
~Both the PHP and JS need another line of code for the option selects, i can do that no sooner than tomorrow, you can look that up though.Cheers

Comment: Your reply in codepen is fantastic!  Thanks very much.  Your a genius!

Comment: @Quang,
:-) TA, i went and styled that form a bit there, go see:-)

Comment: Very nice styling! I'm not supposed to touch the HTML and CSS though.  I went ahead and changed value to Male in HTML.  Codepen and PHP are neat!  I think I want to learn about them next semester.